# Unpublishing used UMBRACO node causes site to crash

Tags: umbraco

I'm using UMBRACO 6.0.2 and I'm seeing an issue where when I unpublish a node that's used elsewhere, UMBRACO doesn't remove the reference node and causes code to crash.

I'd rather not implement logic to handle null nodes, but would rather the actual CMS handle it more gracefully.

Anyone know if that's possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "used elsewhere"?

Comment: So I create 2 nodes/documents (sorry kind of new to this), and node A has a reference to node B. Then I delete node B. If I try to view node A, it crashes. I can see the reference to node B in the config as well as the CMS so I need to manually remove all references to node B. 

As the system grows, it's hard to keep track of these though:(

Comment: When you say "has a reference to node B" do you mean you are using a content picker?

Comment: yup:) sorry for not being clearer

Comment: Can you update the question to include either the template or script that is actually breaking.  It might be rather simple to just do a check to make sure it exists to avoid an error but I'd like to see what is actually failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fas as I know, Umbraco doesn't save references between nodes in a separate table and therefore has no standard option to see which nodes references another node.

However, there is a way to accomplish this by using a query on the database table.
Umbraco keeps the value of documenttype fields in the `cmsPropertyData` table in the field `dataNtext` and the nodeID is kept in the `contentNodeId` field

You could hook into the `Document.AfterUnPublish()` or `Document.BeforeUnPublish()` event and run a query on the `cmsPropertyData` table to check if there are `dataNtext` fields which contain the nodeId you have just unpublished. If so, you also need to unpublish the Document with the nodeID from the `contentNodeId` field.

This solution is not a clean one but it could work. The tricky part is to determine if the node hasn't already been handled/unpublished in your event, otherwise you might create infinite loops ;)